# How to call minified functions from HTML?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert an old (Django) application to use modern JavaScript in the front-end, with minification, modules and so on.

Previously I had a simple `map.js` file which just had a function to draw a map:

```
function setupMap(lng, lat, zoom) {
    // draw map, based on lat/lng etc
}
```

And I called it from my HTML pages directly, after pulling in jQuery and `map.js` (each of the application's pages relates to a particular place, so I want to draw a map of the place):

```
<script src="cdn/link/to/jquery"></script>
<script src="maps.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    setupMap(lat, lng, zoom);
});
</script>
```

That worked fine. But I am trying to do things the modern way. So I would like to bundle jQuery into the file, and I would like to minify the JS.

I have installed jQuery with `npm` and amended the `map.js` file to import it as a module:

```
var $ = require("jquery");
function setupMap(lng, lat, zoom) {
   // etc
```

And I have set `webpack.config.js` to minify the file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.min.js',
        path: __dirname
    },
    module: {}
};
```

And I have updated my HTML to look like this instead:

```
<script src="main.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    setupMap(lat, lng, zoom);
});
</script>
```

But now I get an error from the HTML: `Uncaught ReferenceError: setupMap is not defined`.

What am I doing wrong? How should I be doing things differently? I am lost.

---- UPDATE -----

Thanks for all the answers! I should have clarified that I do need *some* page-specific code, because my Django application has a page for each place (100s of them) and the `lat` and `lng` variables are specific to each page. So I need to call the `setupMap` function separately on each page.

Comment: If you want to modernize your JavaScript, use a module to declare your `setupMap` function and `import` it, rather than depending on globals. If you want to go further, stop using jQuery :).

Comment: You can make them global by adding this at the end of your `index.js`: `Object.assign(window, { $, setupMap });`

Comment: Modules can’t be accessed from the global scope, that’s one of the reasons people prefer working with modules. You need to put your ` $(document).ready()` code in a module too! No code should be in the HTML file!

Answer (score 0):

I Noticed that you're using entry point as index.js in your webpack.config.js
I believe you should use your map.js file as an entry point where you've imported jquery and written custom script.

Or, you can create index.js and use that as an entry point. Adding to that you can import your map.js inside that.

Happy Coding!